# Acceptable wood moisture content for epoxy?

Tags: glue, green-wood, laminating, moisture, gluing

I'm making some I-Beams with glued & screwed 2x4s. I just got my lumber home and it's fresh and green. What is an acceptable moisture content for System Three general purpose epoxy? If there's a range of moisture tolerance between epoxies, would there be a more suitable choice?

Comment: System 3's makers can probably give you the best answer to this! Can I just check one thing, you actually have green wood there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I called System Three and they were very helpful - they strongly recommended only epoxying wood that's reached it's equilibrium moisture content and not in any environment where it could be exposed to water. The issue is that as the wood expands and contracts, the brittle epoxy is more likely than not to crack or tear the bonded surface off, obviating any holding power it had.